# Delete the User Entity and all the data related to the Entity in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, cascading-deletes

I have a Core data model like the User Entity having relationship with multiple entities. I need to delete all the entities that is related to User entity when i try to remove the user in core data.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easies way is to go to all the relationships in the Core Data model editor, select each and choose the `Delete Rule` (which is preset to `Nullify`) to be `Cascade`.

Now all depending entities will be deleted as well.

Here is the [relevant section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW1) in the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the delete rule on your relationships.  `NSCascadeDeleteRule` will cascade deletes through the relationships.

You can find the full details on each delete rule in the Documentation.  Click on Organizer/Documentation and type in `NSDeleteRule` for more details.